# Как поместить пары значений в Map?

Tags: java

Доброго времени суток.

В рамках сохранения данных возник следующий вопрос: если имеются пары значений в формате `List<Object[]>` с повторяющимся первым элементом

101 - 201

101 - 202

101 - 203

102 - 204

102 - 205

102 - 206

103 - 207

103 - 208

103 - 209

Как, скажем, технически правильно поместить данное содержимое в рамках `Map<Integer, List<Integer>>`, сгрупировав в список вторые элементы по схожему первому?

Благодарю.

Comment: Что значит "технически правильно"?

Comment: А , просто фигура речи, не более ... Т.е. корректно, правильно.

Comment: Просто вопрос не понятен. В чем сложность записать в `Map<Integer, List<Integer>>`?

Comment: Возникают некоторые вопросы в плане группировки вторых элементов по схожему первому.

Comment: Какие конкретно вопросы?)

Comment: Каким образом реализовать map.put() с учетом повторяющегося ключа, поместив при этом необходимый value.

Comment: Проверяешь, есть ли по ключу 101 значение, если нет, то создаешь лист, кидаешь в него 201. Если есть, то вытаскиваешь лист, добавляешь в него значение 201 еще одно. Я бы лучше сделал просто лист из объектов класса, в котором есть поля: ключ, значение и количество повторов этого значения.

Comment: А задача группировки списка в карту тривиальна и встречается в интернете повсюду http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21678430/group-a-list-of-objects-by-an-attribute-java

Comment: Да-да, в целом данная идея ясна, следует попробовать подобный вариант. Большое спасибо.

Comment: а вы не можете прочитать про колекции? на собеседовани их любят спрашивать

Comment: @Dmitry08 если вам нужно получать несколько значений, можно поискать колекции например от гугла, или переопределить мап и добавить свой метод. Но лучше посмотреть на другие типы колекций

Comment: Согласен, да, варинатов решений через коллекции разного типа здесь будет довольно много. Благодарю.

Answer (score 1):

Почему бы вам не использовать Stream API из Java 8?

```
List<Integer[]> integers = ....
Map <Integer, List <Integer>> result =
 integers.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(
                                item -> item[0],
                                item -> {
                                  ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
                                  list.add(item[1]);
                                  return list;
                                 },
                                (a, b) -> {
                                  a.addAll(b);
                                  return a;
                                }
                                ));
```

Comment: Да, очень, конечно, интересный вариант, благодарю.